# how to retain original url() when using webpack sass-loader

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to keep my original images/ directory structure post webpack process of a SASS file. I don't want to hash the images or inline them. I want the URL() to look exactly as they were, relative to the sass file like so: ../images/*

original SCSS:

```
 background: url(../images/icon.gif);
```

webpack config:

```
{ test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'raw-loader' },
{ test: /\.scss$/,  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap') },
{ test: /\.(png|gif|bmp)$/,  loader: "file-loader",  query: "name=[path][name].[ext]"            } 
                                        can anything be done here ^^^^^ to make it original path
```

output:

```
background:url(src/images/icons/icon.gif)
```

Comment: using url-loader instead of file-loader seems to be working much better: { test: /\.(png|gif|bmp)$/,  loader: "url-loader", query: "name=[path][name].[ext]" }

Answer (score 6):

use
https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader

```
        {
            test   : /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false']
        }, {
            test   : /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false' , 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
        }
```

and for copy images use
new CopyWebpackPlugin
https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin